# Error Handling with LastFM API and simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, last.fm

I'm using simplexml_load_file to pull album information from the LastFM API and having no problems when the requested album matches.

However, when the album is not found, LastFM returns an [error](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=273f3dc84c2d55501f3dc25a3d61eb39&artist=Martha%20&%20The%20Vandellas&album=Hitsville%20USA,%20Vol.%201%20%281959-1971%29&autocorrect=0), which causes the code below to output a "failed to open stream" error.

**I can see that LastFM is giving me exactly what I need, but am unsure how to proceed. What is the proper way to update the code so that this error/error code is correctly handled?**

Code:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=".$apikey."&artist=".$artist."&album=".$album."&autocorrect=".$autocorrect);

$albums = $feed->album;
foreach($albums as $album) {

    $name = $album->name;
    $img = $album->children();
    $img_big = $img->image[4];
    $img_small = $img->image[2];
    $releasedate = $album->releasedate;
    $newdate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($releasedate));

    if ($img == "") {
            $img = $emptyart; }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working along the lines of evaluating the state of the URL prior to passing it to `simplexml_load_file`, I tried `get_headers`, and that, coupled with an if/else statement, seems to have gotten things working.

```
$url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=".$apikey."&artist=".$artist."&album=".$album."&autocorrect=".$autocorrect;

$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request') {
    $img_big = $emptyart;
    $img_small = $emptyart;
    }

else {
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $albums = $feed->album;
    foreach($albums as $album) {

        $name = $album->name;
        $img = $album->children();
        $img_big = $img->image[4];
        $img_small = $img->image[2];
        $releasedate = $album->releasedate;
        $newdate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($releasedate));

        if ($img == "") {
            $img_big = $emptyart;
            $img_small = $emptyart;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request') {
      $img_big = $emptyart;
      $img_small = $emptyart;
   }
```

That will break with a 403 error ...

Method 1 (not practical):
Basically you can mute the error with @ and check if your $feed is empty. In that case, "some error" has happened, either an error with your url or a status failed from last.fm.

```
    $feed = @simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=".$apikey."&artist=".$artist."&album=".$album."&autocorrect=".$autocorrect);
    if ($feed)
    {
        // fetch the album info
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No results found.";
    }
```

In both ways, you get no results so you can probably satisfy your needs and showing "No results found" instead of showing him "Last.fm error status code, etc.."

Method 2 (recommended) - Use curl:

```
    function load_file_from_url($url) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.test.com/');
        $str = curl_exec($curl);

        if(str === false)
        {
            echo 'Error loading feed, please try again later.';
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        return $str;
    }

    function load_xml_from_url($url) {
        return @simplexml_load_string(load_file_from_url($url));
    }

    function getFeed($feedURL)
    {
        $feed = load_xml_from_url($feedURL);
        if ($feed)
        {
                if ($feed['status'] == "failed")
            {
                echo "FAIL";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "WIN";
            }
        }
        else {echo "Last.fm error";}
    }

    /* Example:
       Album: Heritage
       Artist: Opeth
    */

    $url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=273f3dc84c2d55501f3dc25a3d61eb39&artist=opeth&album=hwwXCvuiweitage&autocorrect=0";
    $feed = getFeed ($url);
    // will echo FAIL

    $url2 = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=273f3dc84c2d55501f3dc25a3d61eb39&artist=opeth&album=heritage&autocorrect=0";
    $feed2 = getFeed ($url2);
    // will echo WIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to first get the url, check if it doesn't contain the error, and then use simplexml_load_string instead?

Comment: I tried something along perhaps-similar lines, using  file_get_contents and an If statement, but only received a different error. How would you get and check the URL?